# Textos não renderizam dentro de 2 .map()

Tags: javascript, array, react, react-native, array-multidimensional

Tenho um array dentro de outro array e gostaria de imprimir na tela dentro de um `<Text>`, porém não estou tendo sucesso.

Os dados no state:

```
areas: [
  nomearea: 'Café',
  periodos: [
    {
      colaboradores: [
        {
          nome: 'João'
        }, 
        {...}, {...}, {...}
      ]
    }
  ]
]
```

Em `render()` estou tentando algo parecido:

```
<ScrollView>
    {
        this.state.areas.map(area => {
            area.periodos.map(periodo => {
                periodo.colaboradores.map(colaborador => {
                    return (
                        <Text>
                            {colaborador.nome}
                        </Text>
                    )
                })
            })
        }
    }
</ScrollView>
```

Acredito que seja algo em referência aos `map()`, `return()` e/ou `{ }`, porém não encontro a forma correta de corrigir.
No `console.log()` está correndo tudo como deveria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ScrollView>
    {
        this.state.areas.map(area => {
           return area.periodos.map(periodo => {
                return periodo.colaboradores.map(colaborador => {
                    return (
                        <Text>
                            {colaborador.nome}
                        </Text>
                    )
                })
            })
        }
    }
</ScrollView>
```

Bastava adicionar os **return**.
Não estava sendo retornado nada ao componente.

Answer (score 0):

Existe um erro de sintaxe no state declarado. Da forma como está estruturado, deveria ser um array de objetos, onde cada objeto corresponde à uma área.

A estrutura abaixo deve funcionar com o seu código:

```
areas: [{
  nomearea: 'Café',
  periodos: [
    {
      colaboradores: [
        {
          nome: 'João'
        }, 
        {...}, {...}, {...}
      ]
    }
  ]
}, {
  nomearea: 'Aveia',
  periodos: [
    {
      colaboradores: [
        {
          nome: 'Maria'
        }, 
        {...}, {...}, {...}
      ]
    }
  ]
}, {...}]
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas o problema persistiria.
Acabei escrevendo o state errado mesmo.

Comment: A solução está no return.
Não é impresso nada pois não há retorno da função.